# How do I create new unix executable (.sh?) files for the terminal to use as commands?

Tags: bash, unix

I'd like to make some files to put in my /usr/bin folder (Mac OS) and be able to run them by typing the name to the terminal, like the commands *gcc*, *cd*, or *vim* (those are all in that folder). When I open such a file as text, it appears encrypted, so I'm not sure how to create one or what extension to use. Thank you.

Comment: You can just drop the extension completely, it doesn't matter.

Comment: For whom downvoted it, please make a comment explaining your reason. It is polite and will help everybody else.

Comment: You should consider changing your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (perhaps in your `~/.bashrc`) but don't mess an important system directory like `/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 11):

The files you see in `/usr/bin` are not encrypted - they're compiled code in machine language different from bash scripts. You can however have scripts also in the `/usr/bin` location and have them run exactly as you are expecting.

In order to do that, you will have to create an executable script file. In unix, scripts are not identified by file extension but by 2 things:

1. executable bit set on the file permission level
2. Script interpreter header, such as `#!/bin/bash`

For a bash script, you can do the following:

Make a new file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world - My first bash script."
```

Save the file as `hello.sh` (the .sh is just convention, it could be any file name).

Then run `chmod +x hello.sh` and you will be able to run this file as an executable.

Move this file to `/usr/local/bin` and you should be able to run `hello.sh` from command line and it should execute your program.

Comment: Don't put custom commands un `/usr/bin`,  `/usr/local/bin` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can create scripts, for example in bash, make the file executable with `chmod` and put the file path in your `$PATH`.

Example:
Create a new file called `myscript.sh`, you can use `vi` or any editor you prefer.
Add the content below on it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world!"
```

Now make it executable:

```
chmod u+x my script.sh
```

You can run your script like this `./myscript.sh` or add it to your path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
```

Now you can just run with the name, like `myscript.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Programs such as `gcc` and `cd` are not encrypted, but compiled; however, if you create a shell script (without `.sh` as suffix; the `.sh` file extension for a shell script is optional) and place it in `/usr/bin` or any PATH location, and you `chmod +x <script-path>` (to give execute permission) then you can directly use that as a command.

Note: use [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to mention the script interpreter, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or equivalent for korn shell, python, etc.